Flask-SQLAlchemy: DetachedInstanceError
I've been trying to create a blog with Flask-SQLAlchemy. I have two DB objects: User and Post, which have a bi-directional relationship to each other. Whenever my homepage tries to access the author property of a post, it brings this error:

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Post at
0x105885280> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of
attribute 'author' cannot proceed (Background on this error at:
https://sqlalche.me/e/20/bhk3)

This is how I've set up my database:
db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base, session_options={
    'expire_on_commit': False
})
db.init_app(app)

db.session.expire_on_commit = False

class Post(db.Model):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    author_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    author: Mapped["User"] = relationship('User', back_populates="posts")
    date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)
    subtitle: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)
    body: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=False)
    image_url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    posts: Mapped[List["Post"]] = relationship('Post', back_populates="author")

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

My home route renders recent posts:
@app.route("/")
def home():
    logged_in = current_user.is_active
    is_admin = False
    if current_user.is_active:
        is_admin = current_user.id == 1

    with app.app_context():
        posts = db.session.execute(db.select(Post).order_by(Post.id))
        posts = list(posts.scalars())[::-1]

    return render_template("index.html", recent_posts=posts[0:(recent_posts_size)], year=year, logged_in=logged_in, is_admin=is_admin)

This is my homepage's HTML:
{% extends 'components/template.html' %}
{% block web_title %}Rephy's Blog{% endblock %}
{% block style %}
header.masthead {
    background-image: url('static/img/home-bg.jpg')
}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Rephy's Blog{% endblock %}
{% block subtitle %}Welcome! Dive into the world of recent computer science breakthroughs, new technologies, and so much more with my blog!{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                    <!-- Post preview-->
                    {% for post in recent_posts %}
                    <div class="post-preview">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('post', id=post.id) }}">
                            <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                            <h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.subtitle }}</h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="post-meta">
                            Posted by
                            <a href="#!">{{ post.author }}</a>
                            on {{ post.date }}
                            {% if is_admin %}
                            <a href="{{ url_for('delete_post', id=post.id) }}">✘</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Divider-->
                    <hr class="my-4" />
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if is_admin %}
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" href="{{ url_for('new_post') }}">Create New Post</a></div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

I've tried setting 'expire-on-commit' to False to get rid of the error, but that still won't work. Also, if I try using a non-existent column, Jinja completely ignores it. Using any existing column besides Author works perfectly.
If you can help, that'd be great.

In the template, you are accessing Post.author. However because author is a relationship it is not automatically fetched when you query for Post objects. When the access occurs in the template, SQLAlchemy emits a query to fetch the User instance corresponding to the Post.author, but the session is no longer active and hence you get the DetachedInstanceError.
To prevent this, either set lazy='joined' on the relationship, so that Post.author is always fetched when a Post is fetched
author: Mapped["User"] = relationship('User', lazy='joined', back_populates="posts")

or specify it as an option in the relevant query:
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload
...
posts = db.session.execute(db.select(Post).options(joinedload(Post.author)).order_by(Post.id))

The above examples should solve the problem, but be aware that there are many approaches to relationship loading in SQLAlchemy - it's worth familiarising yourself with them to ensure you pick the right one for the task in hand.

Btw you don't need to use app_context inside a route.
